# Magento admin login slow and saving product takes time

Tags: php, mysql, magento

My scenario is , I have upgraded magetno from 1.3 to 1.7,
I have overridden some core modules in magento.
The db has around 8000 products.

The issue is on live server sometimes it takes 10 mins to get login to admin side
and when adding a new product its taking so much time.

What would be the issue?

Comment: There are several methods of trying to find the cause. First off, check all log files (domain error log, magento system.log and exception.log). If you find no clues there, you might consider requesting support from your webhoster. They might see whether MySQL has difficulties or not. If so you might think about using New Relic to screen the Magento code, it might point you to the right extension causing this problem.

Comment: @Luceos, I didn't get you last sentence, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: New Relic is a server application that is great for analyzing php code. Thus on high (critical) load moments it will point you to the exact database or php call. This only works on New Relic Pro, but a trial is free.. (Ps not alleged to them in any way). So sometimes magento extensions are not optimized for its current version, with new relic you might actually see which one in a matter of seconds (after installation by a sysadmin).

Comment: Ok thanks i will look for that tool

Comment: Yes but first try the first steps.. Logs and load.

Comment: Actually i alreay went through all the steps, nothing is there, one issue would be logging data, but we are purging it on daily basis